# Why can't we create instance of Collections class (not Collection Interface)?

Tags: java, collections

`Collections` is a public class, then we can call its implicit default constructor. It doesn't have private constructor, which would prevent object creation or force to have static factory method. When  I do instantiate as `new Collections()`, i get error as "Constructor not visible". In short why can't we have instance of `java.util.Collections` class? Thanks.

Comment: What do you think it would do?

Comment: My `java.util.Collections` class does have a private constructor!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html): "This class consists exclusively of static methods that operate on or return collections."

In other words, `Collections` is just a collection of methods. An instance of it would not make any sense. It is just like the math functions: You don't have an instance of math, you just use the functions.

It is not an `interface` as it has concrete methods.

Comment: Thanks, Which concept prevent us from creating an instance of Collections class. I agree it is useless, I am asking just for curiosity. Thanks again.

Comment: @Ahamed: see my comment, there is a private (invisible) constructor

Answer (score 4):

The reason for the "Constructor not visible" message is that the constructor is private (line 73), or at least according to [this site](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Collections.java.html) . And as others already stated, what would you do with an instance of this class as it only contains static methods

```
// Suppresses default constructor, ensuring non-instantiability.
private Collections() {
}
```

Comment: Thanks. In source code it is there but the decompiler, which helped me to peek inside the class didn't show the private constructor.

Comment: @Ahamed - then there's something wrong with the decompiler you are using.  Try using `javap`.

Comment: I have tried `javap` command. It is not showing that private constructor, don't know why, may be because it is empty constructor. There is a private constructor which resides inside the class file and prevents instantiation, but is not showing up in decompiler or javap command :)